# Covering argument

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

In proving Harnak's inequality (I am referring to this article: "On Harnack’s Theorem for Elliptic 
Differential Equations"Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics
Volume 14, Issue 3 ),

Moser reduces the general case of a domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a compact subset $D$ to two concentric cubes, the one with greater side lenght being open and the interior one being closed.

He justifies this by a "covering argument", I am trying to understand what this might be:

I think two facts are used:

1) $\Omega$ is the union of countably many open cubes $Q_1,Q_2,..$.

2) $\Omega$ is the union of countably many almost disjoint closed cubes $Q'_1,Q'_2,..$.

So obviously we can find finite cover for $D$, $\{Q_1,...Q_m\}$
what I am not sure about is whether or not we can say that $D$ is almost the union of finitely many closed cubes $\{Q'_1,..,Q'_k\}$. 
If this is true then we could conclude the covering argument (I think) considering precompacts $Q_i\cap Q'_j\subset Q_i$ and then just take some maxima.

Can anyone tell me if I am on the wrong track or if this is something like what the author had in mind?

Thanks.